# Moveit2, ROS2: Install moveit_py

Tags: ros2, moveit

Im trying to install moveit_py on Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 humble.

Installing from source the whole moveit2 is the only way to use those python modules?

I tried to build just the moveit_py in my ros2 workspace but it fails with a bunch of errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install with:
sudo apt install ros-iron-moveit-py